# Cannot load local files in electron js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, electron, content-security-policy, electron-forge

**OBJECTIVE**:  to load a local video file from hard drive

**Techstack** :  react electron v16 electronforge v6 webpack

my **index.html** looks like this

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>app</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="app"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

i have NOT passed any content security policies,

in my  **videoComponent.tsx**

```
 <video
     id="video1"
     ref={videoRef}
     className="video"
    src ={`priviliged://${videoPath}`} // videopath = " E:\videofolder\videofile.mp4"
></video>
```

as according to  https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/api/protocol#protocolregisterschemesasprivilegedcustomschemes
A standard scheme adheres to what RFC 3986 calls generic URI syntax. For example http and https are standard schemes, while file is not.

i decided to make a custom priviliged protocol as per the docs
in **electron.main.ts**

```js
  app.whenReady().then(() => {
  protocol.registerSchemesAsPrivileged([
    { scheme: "priviliged", privileges: { bypassCSP: true } },
  ]);
});
```

and applied to **videocomponent.tsx**
`
but i still get this error

```
Refused to load media from 'priviliged://E:\videofolder\videofile.mp4' 
because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "default-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' data:". 
Note that 'media-src' was not explicitly set, so 'default-src' is used as a fallback.
```

what should i do?

Comment: well, I think this is not a bug in my stack or code, just try the latest electron forge typescript webpack template and set web security to none and just add a video tag with src to the path of any local file.
you will have the csp error

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using file protocol,

Add the following line in your in index.html file

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src 'none'">
```

Comment: Adding another policy will require that both need to pass. This one will block everything.

Comment: I tried both of these methods
i get either this or more CSP errors ;-;
```index.js:842 Uncaught EvalError: Refused to evaluate a string as JavaScript because 'unsafe-eval' is not an allowed source of script in the following Content Security Policy directive: "default-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' data: filesystem:".

    at Object../node_modules/webpack-dev-server/client/index.js?```

Answer (score 0):

You will need to modify the content-security-policy. Your current policy is "default-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' data:", which will allow any script from the host where your page loads, any inline script and anything via the data scheme. To allow loading local files you will likely need to add "filesystem:" to your CSP as such:

default-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' data: filesystem: